# Como verificar os 4 elementos verticais e horizontais em uma matriz baseada na posição atual?

Tags: php, javascript, array, matriz

Vamos supor que eu tenha uma matriz desta maneira:

```
$matrix = [[0, 1, 1, 0],
           [1, 1, 1, 0],
           [1, 0, 0, 0]];
```

Imagine que esteja fazendo um laço e capturando a posição desta matriz conforme o exemplo abaixo, sendo **y** as linhas com meus *arrays* e **x** as posições de cada linha (não sei se está correto a maneira de construir isso):

```
<?php

 $data = getHierarchyMatrix(['x'=>2,'y'=>1], $matrix);

 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($data);
 function getHierarchyMatrix($currentXY, $matrix) {

    $currentX = $currentXY['x'];
    $currentY = $currentXY['y'];

    foreach ($matrix as $currentLine => $arrayLine) {

           if ($currentLine >= $currentY) {
              $previousY = ($currentLine-1);
              $nextY = ($currentLine+1);
              if (isset($matrix[$previousY])) {
                 $previousValueY = $matrix[$previousY];
              }
              if (isset($matrix[$currentLine+1])) {
                 $nextValueY = $matrix[$nextY];
              }

              foreach ($arrayLine as $current => $value) {
                  if ($current == $currentX) {
                      $currentValue = $value;
                      $previousX = ($current - 1);
                      if (isset($matrix[$current][$previousX])) {
                         $previousValueX = $matrix[$current][$previousX];
                      }
                      $nextX  = ($current + 1);
                      if (isset($matrix[$current][$nextX])) {
                         $nextValueX = $matrix[$current][$nextX];
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }

    return [
             'atual'    => $currentValue,
             'esquerda' => $previousValueX,
             'direita'  => $nextValueX,
             'em cima'  => $previousValueY,
             'em baixo' => $nextValueY
           ];
 }
```

O problema é basicamente pegar a posição x e y e os 4 elementos que os cercam, eu não sei se estou fazendo isso direto... mas preciso fazer o quadrante baseado na posição atual, como poderia fazer isso? Creio que meu método não esteja muito bem elaborado. Talvez aja alguma forma de fazer isso usando alguma função do PHP que desconheço, alguém poderia me ajudar... Seu que existem métodos que poderiam auxiliar nisso, como:

```
$atual = current($array); 
$proximo = next($array);  
$anterior = prev($array); 
$ultimo = end($array);
```

> **Obs:** Também vou precisar dessa fórmula para uma versão em JavaScript

Comment: Não rola pegar os elementos usando como referência a posição do próprio elemento? Por exemplo, suponhamos que o elemento esteja em `1,1`. Os elementos que você busca estão em `0,1`, `1,0`, `2,1` e `1,2`.

Comment: Rola, só não sei como fazer isso. Mas no exemplo já estou pegando a posição do próprio elemento.

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti, obrigado também pela resposta. Ajudou a refletir sobre tudo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagino que assim irá resolver seu problema:

```
function getHierarchyMatrix($currentXY, $matrix) {
    $currentX = $currentXY['x'];
    $currentY = $currentXY['y'];

    if(isset($matrix[$currentXY['y']][$currentXY['x']])){
        $atual = $matrix[$currentXY['y']][$currentXY['x']];

        $left = isset($matrix[$currentXY['y']][$currentXY['x']-1]) ? 
                $matrix[$currentXY['y']][$currentXY['x']-1] : false;
        $right = isset($matrix[$currentXY['y']][$currentXY['x']+1]) ?
                $matrix[$currentXY['y']][$currentXY['x']+1] : false;
        $top = isset($matrix[$currentXY['y']-1][$currentXY['x']]) ? 
                $matrix[$currentXY['y']-1][$currentXY['x']] : false;
        $bottom = isset($matrix[$currentXY['y']+1][$currentXY['x']]) ? 
                $matrix[$currentXY['y']+1][$currentXY['x']] : false;


        return [
            'atual'    => $atual,
            'esquerda' => $left,
            'direita'  => $right,
            'em cima'  => $top,
            'em baixo' => $bottom
            ];
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Acho que eu viajei fazendo `foreach`, se eu preciso pegar só de uma posição, não precisava entra em um loop na matriz. Muito obrigado, funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

A primeira coisa que você deve fazer é validar a posição do elemento de referência, ou seja:

- Se a posição do próprio elemento é válida;
- Se o elemento está entre duas linhas e duas colunas.

Depois dessa validação, basta pegar os elementos desejados com base na posição do elemento de referência, ao qual vamos dar o nome de `$x`:

```
<?php

$a = $x[x-1, y]; // elemento à esquerda
$b = $x[x+1, y]; // elemento à direita
$c = $x[x, y-1]; // elemento acima
$d = $x[x, y+1]; // elemento abaixo
```

Para JavaScript, a lógica é a mesma.